# Jinja2, Ansible, How to create a nested for loop with if statement and update a list while iterating?

Tags: for-loop, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to loop over a list of dictionaries and check if there is more than one Source for the same Group in this type of structure:

```
[{"Device": "CM1LS-05B","Group": "239.216.12.8/32","Source": "10.144.12.8/32"},
 {"Device": "CM1LS-01A","Group": "239.192.9.100/32","Source": "10.144.69.7/32"}]
```

So basically i need to grab each dict in the list and compare it with all other dicts in the list, for each comparison if the dict.groups match then check if the dict.sources match, if they dict.groups match and the dict.sources dont match i need to append both dicts to final_list

heres is what I have:

```
- name: Look for Multicast Groups with More than One Source
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    final_list: []
    my_list: [
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-05B",
            "Group": "239.216.12.8/32",
            "Source": "10.144.12.8/32"
        },
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-01A",
            "Group": "239.192.9.100/32",
            "Source": "10.144.69.7/32"
        },
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-05B",
            "Group": "239.216.48.229/32",
            "Source": "10.144.48.15/32"
        },
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-05B",
            "Group": "239.216.48.40/32",
            "Source": "10.144.65.161/32"
        },
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-01A",
            "Group": "239.208.0.202/32",
            "Source": "172.23.59.16/32"
        },
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-05B",
            "Group": "239.216.48.229/32",
            "Source": "10.144.48.229/32"
        },
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-01A",
            "Group": "239.208.0.203/32",
            "Source": "172.23.59.16/32"
        }
    ]

  tasks:
    - read_csv:
        path: results.csv
      register: lines

    - set_fact:
        final_list:
           "{% for i in my_list %}
               {% for j in my_list %}
                  {% if i[ 'Group' ] == j[ 'Group' ] %}
                     {{ final_list + [ i['Group']] }}
                  {% endif %}
               {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}"
    - debug: var=final_list
```

output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final_list": "   [u'239.216.12.8/32']                    [u'239.192.9.100/32']                    [u'239.216.48.229/32']        [u'239.216.48.229/32']              [u'239.216.48.40/32']                    [u'239.208.0.202/32']              [u'239.216.48.229/32']        [u'239.216.48.229/32']                    [u'239.208.0.203/32']   "
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I think I have something wrong in the jinja2 forloop  if statement's comparison

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there ! Meanwhile note that this is a very verbose templating expression. It might be easier to develop a custom filter where you will be able to manage your data directly in python.

But here we go. This is a possible "ansible only" solution just fixing your actual task. I used yaml scalar folded block so that we can drop outer quotes and write on several lines dropping new lines at the end. I also introduced the white space control markers in your jinja2 template to make sure we don't get any extra characters in the output that could bloat the constructed variable parsing. Lastly, you cannot concatenate the var directly as you tried. You need to calculate the result and output it so that it is assigned to the var.

```
    - set_fact:
        final_list: >-
          {%- set my_result = [] -%}
          {%- for i in my_list -%}
            {%- for j in my_list -%}
              {%- if i['Group'] == j['Group'] -%}
                {{ my_result.append(i['Group']) }}
              {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {{ my_result }}
```

Comment: Thanks much! it worked but I'm getting everything as a string not an array. I couldn't get the results back into the playbook when defining my_result = [] but i kept as final_list and it worked, but im getting it as an array in side double quotes "[ results ]" not [results]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
- set_fact:
        final_list: >-
          {%- for i in my_list -%}
            {%- for j in my_list -%}
              {%- if (i['Group'] == j['Group']) and (i['Source'] != j['Source']) -%}
                {{ my_result + [i,j] }}
              {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
  debug: var= finale_list
```

but I didnt get an array. Instead I got a unicode string:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final_list": "[{u'Device': u'CM1LS-05B', u'Source': u'10.144.48.15/32', u'Group': u'239.216.48.229/32'}, {u'Device': u'CM1LS-20A', u'Source': u'10.144.48.229/32', u'Group': u'239.216.48.229/32'}][{u'Device': u'CM1LS-20A', u'Source': u'10.144.48.229/32', u'Group': u'239.216.48.229/32'}, {u'Device': u'CM1LS-05B', u'Source': u'10.144.48.15/32', u'Group': u'239.216.48.229/32'}]"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

desired output need to look like:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final_list": [
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-05B",
            "Group": "239.216.48.229/32",
            "Source": "10.144.48.15/32"
        },
        {
            "Device": "CM1LS-20A",
            "Group": "239.216.48.229/32",
            "Source": "10.144.48.229/32"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```